# .on click .css doesn't work at second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*THE MAIN IDEA:*

I have 16 blocks (div) and some buttons (a). Each button means some set of blocks. Initially all the blocks are "ON". If I press any button, I turn "OFF" related set of blocks. I use grey color (#999999) to mark them as OFF. If block is already turned OFF, it should stay turned OFF.

**PROBLEM:**

When I press one of the buttons first time, it works. Second press on button - doesn't work.

---

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* set of blocks that are "ON" */
    var ONs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

    /* different sets of blocks to turn them OFF  */
    var logi = [1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16];
    var etik = [2,3,5,8,9,12,14,15];
    var sens = [2,4,5,7,9,11,14,16];
    var intu = [1,3,6,8,10,12,13,15];
    var exst = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15];
    var intr = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16];
    var raci = [3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14];
    var irra = [1,2,5,6,11,12,15,16];               

    $("body").on("click",".mybtn", function() {

        myBlocks = $("div.blocks"); /* get blocks */
        var dih = $(this).attr ("data-arr");
        var tmp = eval (dih);

        for (var i in ONs) {
            for (var j in tmp) {
                if (ONs[i] == tmp [j]) {
                    ONs.splice (i, 1);
                }
            }
        }


        /* turn "OFF" blocks */  
        for (var i = 0; i < ONs.length; i++) { 
            if (i in ONs) {                      
                $("div.blocks").eq(ONs[i]-1).css("backgroundColor", "#999999");
            }
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

---

**CSS**

```
.blocks {width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: #000000; margin: 20px 10px; float:left;}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<!-- My Buttons. I press them to turn "OFF" some set of blocks -->
<a href="#" data-arr="logi" class="mybtn">logi</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="etik" class="mybtn">etik</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="sens" class="mybtn">sens</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="intu" class="mybtn">intu</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="exst" class="mybtn">exst</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="intr" class="mybtn">intr</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="raci" class="mybtn">raci</a>
<a href="#" data-arr="irra" class="mybtn">irra</a>

<!-- My Blocks. They all are "ON" at the first moment -->
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
<div class="blocks"></div>
```

Comment: It's a logical error with the way you keep splicing the arrays and looping over them. As a sidenote, you shouldn't use for .. in loops on arrays, and definitively not `eval`

Comment: Is this what you want -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qL3nP/** ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @adeneo pointed out, you keep on splicing the array till it will get emptied on the 2nd run.

An easy fix is moving `ONs` inside the click handler.

```
$("body").on("click", ".mybtn", function () {
        var ONs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
[...]
```

Now you may notice that you are missing the actuall removal of colors of the disabled blocks.

Instead of editing the style directly you can add/remove a class for the disabled blocks.

```
$("body").on("click", ".mybtn", function () {
    var ONs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
    myBlocks = $("div.blocks"); /* get blocks */
    myBlocks.removeClass('dis');
    var dih = $(this).attr("data-arr");
    var tmp = eval(dih);

    for (var i in ONs) {
        for (var j in tmp) {
            if (ONs[i] == tmp[j]) {
                ONs.splice(i, 1);

            }
        }
    }

    /* turn "OFF" blocks */
    for (var i = 0; i < ONs.length; i++) {
        if (i in ONs) {
            $("div.blocks").eq(ONs[i] - 1).addClass("dis");
        }
    }

    return false;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cJL6/

Comment: Not really contributing to the answer, but this fiddle looks a bit cleaner (and has animations!): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cJL6/1/)

Comment: In this case all switched OFF blocks at first click disappears on second click. A want to kind of collect OFF states.

Comment: @beratishka then you only have to remove the `myBlocks.removeClass('dis');` from the click handler. You can then get the disabled blocks by (in my example) the class *dis*

Answer (score 1):

I made small changes to your jQuery code. working for me.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L92LE/)**

> Highlights of my changes:
>
> - Removed `for in` loop.
> - Removed **Eval**
> - Made the array into an Object for easy manipulations.

#### JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* set of blocks that are "ON" */
    var ONs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

    /* different sets of blocks to turn them OFF  */
    var obj = {
        logi: [1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 16],
        etik: [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15],
        sens: [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16],
        intu: [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15],
        exst: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15],
        intr: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16],
        raci: [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14],
        irra: [1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 12, 15, 16]
    }


    $("body").on("click", ".mybtn", function () {

        myBlocks = $("div.blocks"); /* get blocks */
        var tmp = obj[$(this).attr("data-arr")];
        // var tmp = (dih);

        myBlocks.css("backgroundColor", "");
        /* turn "OFF" blocks */
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            myBlocks.eq(tmp[i] - 1).css("backgroundColor", "#999999");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L92LE/)**

Comment: @cbuckley Thanks.. but realized just now that adeneo had already provided a good solution in above comments. :)

Comment: I want to "collect" OFF-states of blocks. When I press some btn second time OFF-states of first press should stay OFF.